# how to re-migrate a laravel migration after deleting the table

Tags: php, laravel

after I've manually deleted a table in mysql, I run the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

and I get this:

```
Nothing to migrate.
```

it only works the first time, how to re-run the migration in laravel?

Comment: your laravel version??

Comment: @Davit the last one

Comment: The concept of migration is always advance and never go to back. When you say that a table was deleted manually of this database, this means that this problem should be solved the way it was created. Instead of creating a new migration and running it (and manage all problems that this action involves), create the table manually based on migration creation table specifications.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Laravel keeps a record of migrations that have been run. You need to go to the migrations table and delete the migration record. Laravel does this so that it knows which migrations have been run so that it doesn't run them again and so that in the case of a rollback, it knows the last batch of migrations which were done.

This may help https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations

Answer (score 16):

Try `composer dump-autoload` AND `php artisan config:cache`

if not working also Try `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

OR Also Delete Migration table in database.

Answer (score 8):

You can  simply do: php  artisan  migrate: fresh  to  re-migrate your  migration and if  you have  seeder  data  then  you  simply  do: php artisan  migrate: fresh -- seed

Answer (score 4):

That is the expected behaviour if you manually delete a table, because the previous batch migration job has already been deployed (in **migrations** table).

- IF you want to re-migrate all the database, you can simply do: `php artisan migrate:refresh`.
- IF you want to make sure your database to be clean with your latest changes, you can drop your entire database tables and do `php artisan migrate` again. Also, you can try `php artisan migrate --seed` if you have any seeder.

Comment: Or drop everything, migrate and seed all in one command with `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Answer (score 4):

If you delete a table by hand, will have to delete the record from "migration" table too. This way when artisan migrate checks if your migration are not in "migration" table will migrate the unregistered ones.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is drop the table from the database and then rename the migration last number and do

```
php artisan migrate
```

This doesn't recreate all the tables.